# HTML5 Audio Load Event?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there a load event that fires when an audio has finished loading? I am creating an audio element like so.

```
var myAudio = new Audio("mySound.mp3");
myAudio.load();
```

Tried adding an eventListener like so but it does not seem to fire.

```
myAudio.addEventListener("load",soundLoaded,false);
```

Comment: Have you considered [buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) and looking through its source?

Comment: Interesting Library. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. By looking at the Docs "canPlayThrough" seems to be what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

It sounds like you want the "[canplaythrough](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp)" event. This fires when the browser thinks it can play the whole audio file without stopping.

Try:

```
myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', soundLoaded, false);
```

There are 7 events that fire in this order when an audio file is loaded:

1. loadstart
2. durationchange
3. loadedmetadata
4. loadeddata
5. progress
6. canplay
7. canplaythrough

Please note this is not supported in Internet Explorer versions before 9.

Answer (score 6):

Audio tag implementation very depends on Browser. Its supported I would say less than video tag as it was in hype after Steve Jobs speech on Flash vs HTML5 holy war, funny enough it is least supported by Safari.
And its true whats working well for Video tag (on Event handler) not working for Audio tag, but what good that Statuses are still correct. 
For example :

```
var a = new Audio();
```

- `a.networkState` and `a.readyState` - by checking this every second on
  timer you can easily    get idea about loading and playing progress.

Other interesting properties:

- `seeking` - True if UA currently seeking
- `seekable` - TimeRange object to which possible to seek.
- `played` - `TimeRange` what UA has been played.
- `paused` - True if playback paused.
- `ended` - True if playback ended.
- `currentTime` - Return/Set playback position in seconds.
- `duration`

Do not forget using `canPlayType(type)` - returns `"probably"` and `"maybe"`

Update: Consider looking at SoundManager2 - http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 0):

Audio load event: (React)

```
    <audio
        controls
        src={content.fullUrl}
        onCanPlay={() => setIsLoading(false)}
    >
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
```